# How can I access views from layout containing merge tag is included in another layout?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I use Android Studio 3.6-RC1 and build tools version 3.6.0-rc01 and encountered an issue with ViewBinding feature:

I have activity_test.xml file with the following markup:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/view_merged"
        layout="@layout/merge_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And merge_view.xml with following markup:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Merge view" />
</merge>
```

Activity code looks like the following:

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.viewMerged.label.text = "New text"

    }
}
```

Problem is when I try to access TextView from merged layout, the app throws an exception with the message `java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: viewMerged.`

The generated binding class looks like the following:

```
public final class ActivityTestBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final LinearLayout rootView;

  @NonNull
  public final MergeViewBinding viewMerged;

  private ActivityTestBinding(@NonNull LinearLayout rootView,
      @NonNull MergeViewBinding viewMerged) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
    this.viewMerged = viewMerged;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public LinearLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityTestBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityTestBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_test, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivityTestBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    // The body of this method is generated in a way you would not otherwise write.
    // This is done to optimize the compiled bytecode for size and performance.
    String missingId;
    missingId: {
      View viewMerged = rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_merged);
      if (viewMerged == null) {
        missingId = "viewMerged";
        break missingId;
      }
      MergeViewBinding viewMergedBinding = MergeViewBinding.bind(viewMerged);
      return new ActivityTestBinding((LinearLayout) rootView, viewMergedBinding);
    }
    throw new NullPointerException("Missing required view with ID: ".concat(missingId));
  }
}
```

Am I missing something or there is no way to access views from included layouts with  tags or it is not yet shipped in Android Studio 3.6-RC1?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I wrote an article about using ViewBinding with `<merge>` tag which you can find [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/exploring-viewbinding-in-depth-598925821e41)

Basically, what you need to do is

- Don't give `<include>` tag any ID.
- Call `bind()` method of generated merge layout binding, passing the root view of the layout you included your layout in.
- Access your view from the object of merge binding

For example, you have `merge_view.xml` so you'll have `MergeViewBinding` class generated and this is how you will access the view from this layout.

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val mergeBinding = MergeViewBinding.bind(binding.root)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        mergeBinding.label.text = "New text"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my question, so can't accept it. However, I upvoted your answer and mentioned it in related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147792710

Comment: Not working for me when inflating a layout for a RecyclerView ViewHolder (haven't tried other situations). I get "Missing required view with ID: text1" which is an id in the merge layout. Main layout is a CardView with one child: the include for merge layout

Comment: I think the reason is I had multiple views with ID (@android:id/text1) in the hierarchy (not spotted because lots of nested includes) and this seems to confuse the Binding

Comment: @VolodymyrBuberenko Didn't see that. It seems that the bind() method is not there for <merge> or just a workaround. let's see what they comment.

Comment: In my case I have a layout that includes another layout multiple times (note: there is no merge layout). The problem occurs when the included layout's root has an ID. So I just needed to remove that (refer to the ID of the include tag instead).

Comment: I think the "multiple times" thing is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a good approach. However the bind call will try to cast the root layout of the merged layout to the root layout of the activity layout. This is causing a ClassCastException. What worked for me ironically was 

val mergeViewBinding = MergeViewBinding.bind(binding.root.findViewById(R.id.root_id_in_mergelayout)

Comment: @LakshmanChilukuri i think this is the current workaround, but, view binding should prevent us using `findViewById`, and looks like google still working on the issue, and it is available only in Android Studio 4.0 & above (beta & canary)

Comment: I've tried this approach, unfortunately, it only works if we did the above approach, when using dynamic views inflation (in runtime), it doesn't works T_T @SomeshKumar

Comment: (AS 3.6.0) I've also found the error happens when using DataBinding in only some of the layouts involved (`<layout>` being the root of only some layouts). I know this question seems more about the lighter ViewBinding, but that was my issue, and that may also cause issues with @SomeshKumar answer ('missing tag' errors). Ultimately, because I was using DataBinding, setting an ID for my `<include>` tags worked fine as long as all layouts involved had `<layout>` as the root element, and I didn't have to keep track of multiple Bindings as described by @SomeshKumar.

Comment: for future readers: this also doesn't works for `<merge>` that has multiple child, it won't gives NPE for first child, but others will throws NPE

Comment: @mochadwi `<merge>` usually has multiple children... it works for me. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: that's weird, lemme try it again for other usecase @SomeshKumar

Comment: I keep getting "view must have a tag"

Comment: Have edited another method also , without using mergeBinding

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the binding of the view/file. Here is an example:

```
import ch.zkb.mobile.bank.databinding.MyFragmentBinding
import ch.zkb.mobile.bank.databinding.MyMergeBinding

class MyFragment : (R.layout.my_fragment) {

    private val binding by viewBinding(MyFragmentBinding::bind)
    private val mergeBinding by viewBinding(MyMergeBinding::bind)

    ...
}
```

View example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/my_merge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure, you build it first, so the Binding is generated.

Comment: From which lib is ` by viewBinding`?

Comment: Checkout https://medium.com/flobiz-blog/fragment-view-binding-initialisation-using-delegates-8cd50b41e1d2 for more information. There are also more other pages. Search for "FragmentViewBindingDelegate" - makes you life much simpler ;)